# What are the units of the gravitational constant of the universe $G$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, unit-of-measure

This is a homework question from a precalculus class that I'm a TA for.

> The force $F$ between two bodies of mass $m_1$ kilograms
>   and $m_2$ kilograms whose centers of mass are a distance $r$ meters
>   apart is given by the formula 
>   \begin{equation*}
>    F = \frac{G m_1 m_2}{r^2}
>     \,,
> \end{equation*}
>   where $G$ is the gravitational constant of the universe.
>   What are the units of the gravitational constant $G$?

I wanted to write up a thorough solution to this exercise for my class, and figured I'd post it online to help anyone else who may wander across it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we want to figure out what the units of $G$ are,
first we should rewrite the given formula with $G$ isolated:
\begin{equation*}
    F = \frac{G m_1 m_2}{r^2}
    \quad\implies\quad
    G = \frac{F r^2}{m_1 m_2}
\end{equation*}
Since this is an equality,
the units on the left-hand side (so the units of $G$)
will be the same as the units on the right-hand side.
We recall that since $F=ma$ 
the units of force are $\mathrm{kg}(\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}^2)$.
So the units of the right-hand side must be
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{\mathrm{kg}\frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{s}^2}\,\mathrm{m}^2}
         {\mathrm{kg}\,\mathrm{kg}}
    \,,
\end{equation*}
which we can write more cleanly as
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{\mathrm{m}^3}{\mathrm{kg}\,\mathrm{s}^2}
    \,.
\end{equation*}
So these are the units of $G$.